# jquery checked and selected and print values together

Tags: jquery

Current i use filter and map to check all checked inputs and print values:

```
<input class="checkboxinput" type="checkbox" name="products" data-price1m="375" data-price12m="338" value="Additional Azure Pack | 1C 4GB RAM">
<input class="checkboxinput" type="checkbox" name="products" data-price1m="375" data-price12m="338" value="Additional Azure Pack | 1C 4GB RAM">
<input class="checkboxinput" type="checkbox" name="products" data-price1m="375" data-price12m="338" value="Additional Azure Pack | 1C 4GB RAM">

 var elems = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
                  if(elems.is(':checked')){
                     $('#totalamount').val(
                             elems.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                                var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.amountOrder').val());
                                if(amount == '0'){ amount=1;}

                                if(groupSelected == 'm'){
                                 var price = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').data('price1m'));
                                }else{
                                 var price = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').data('price12m'));
                                }
                                return this.value+' כמות: ' + amount  + ' סה"כ: ' + amount*price;
                            }).get().join(" ->\n")
                        );
                  }
```

The above code is working perfect only for checkbox,
I read some articles: [How do I total checked and selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888408/how-do-i-total-checked-and-selected)

But if i want to combine my current filter with checked and selected its possible ?

I have no idea how to do this..i seek hours on google and came to here.

I am new here and hope to some help,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answer to myself..

Can combine checked and selected this way:

```
 var elems = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked,#ITselect option:selected');

                     $('#totalamount').val(
                             elems.map(function() {
                                var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.amountOrder').val());
                                if(amount == '0'){ amount=1;}

                                if(groupSelected == 'm'){
                                 var price = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').data('price1m'));
                                }else{
                                 var price = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').data('price12m'));
                                }
                                return this.value+' כמות: ' + amount  + ' סה"כ: ' + amount*price;
                            }).get().join(" ->\n")
                        );
```

little tweek working awesome.